# Dynamic Editable Checkbox

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an android activity screen which displays a table with the last column as editable checkbox. Can someone help get started on this?

Also I was wondering if there was a tool like `ArrayAdapter`, `Listadapter` which displays your data from an array, except what I want in this is with the checkboxes for each row. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced one such problem for which I created a customized listview which looks like a table, and every row you can dynamically fill the data using custom listview adapter.

for editable checkbox, on click of the row you can open an edittext in dialog and after that you replace it with the checkbox text.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your replies.
I created this table layout, with two text views and one checkBox.
It looks pretty much the way I wanted it look like,but my two TextViews stick to each other,theres no padding of spaces between them.How shall I do this dynamically? thanks